# Handling functions

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a C code using Visual Studio Professional 2012. 
I have a question regarding writing functions.

Suppose I write at the beginning of the file a prototype of a function and after a few lines, I define the function and writes its content. for example,

```
 void hello (int num); // prototype

 void main() 
 {    
     int i;
     bla-bla-bla
     hello (i);
     .... 
 }

 void hello (int num) // definition
 {    
     bla-bla-bla ...
 }
```

Suppose I want to change the function's prototype. Is there any option that the function's definition will be changed automatically by Visual Studio ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking for a rename of a function prototype to automatically rename the function definition as well.  If so the answer is unfortunately no.  There is no in the box support for such a semantic rename.

There are 3rd party solutions such as [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) which provide this functionality.  They are generally not free though